# Zabbix integration with prometheus

Tags: time-series, grafana, zabbix, prometheus

We are currently monitoring our network devices with Zabbix but now we want to use Zabbix along with Prometheus for real-time monitoring and powerful alerting of Prometheus.
 How can I integrate my existing Zabbix solution with Prometheus?

Comment: This is unclear. Please describe what functionality you want to achieve.

Comment: Basically I want to poll data from zabbix to prometheus and show real time monitoring in grafana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a [Zabbix to Prometheus](https://github.com/MyBook/zabbix-exporter) exporter that may achieve what you want, but please note that I wouldn't recommend that.

Apart from some temporary migration scenarios I see little use in polling one monitoring system from the other. You're probably better off deploying the appropriate Prometheus exporters (e.g. [SNMP](https://github.com/prometheus/snmp_exporter), if your talking about network devices) and use Prometheus for the whole monitoring setup.

Of course you can still keep your Zabbix setup running side by side, if you need to.